# Web app works in Firefox but not IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I've built this app that displays employee photos stored in several sharepoint folders.  It also displays the employee name extracted from the file name and a previous and next button to move through the photos.

The markup is surrounded by an update panel to prevent the entire page from reloading when you click to view the next photo.

The app is working fine in firefox, but the images do not display in IE8.  Can anyone tell what is causing this?

```
public List<string> photoFileList = new List<string>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            Session["index"] = 0;
            Session["CountOfPictures"] = 0;

            List<string> PhotoFolders = new List<string>();
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\Dept1");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept2");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept3");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept4");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept5”);
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept6");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept7");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept8");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept9");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept10");
            PhotoFolders.Add("\\\\intranet.org\\Photo Album\\Employees\\ Dept11");

            Session["AllPhotoFolders"] = PhotoFolders;

           List<string> AllPhotoFolders = (List<string>)Session["AllPhotoFolders"];

           foreach (string folder in AllPhotoFolders)
           {

               DirSearch(folder);
           }

           Session["AllPhotoFiles"] = photoFileList;
           Image1.ImageUrl = photoFileList[0].Replace("\\", "//");
           var list = (List<string>)Session["AllPhotoFiles"];
           lblName.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(list[0]).Substring(0, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(list[0]).Length - 4).Replace("_", " ");

           Session["CountOfPictures"] = photoFileList.Count;




        }
    }

    void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.JPG"))
        {
            //BulletedList1.Items.Add(f);
            photoFileList.Add(f);
        }

        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            if (!d.EndsWith("_t") && !d.EndsWith("_w")) 
            { DirSearch(d);}

        }

    }


protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int NextIndex = (int)Session["index"];
        int PictureCount = (int)Session["CountOfPictures"];
        NextIndex += 1;

        if (NextIndex == PictureCount)
        {
            NextIndex = 0;
        }

        Session["index"] = NextIndex;
        var list = (List<string>)Session["AllPhotoFiles"];
        Image1.ImageUrl = list[NextIndex].Replace("\\", "//");
        lblName.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(list[NextIndex]).Substring(0,System.IO.Path.GetFileName(list[NextIndex]).Length - 4).Replace("_"," ");
        lblName.Visible = true;
    }




protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int NextIndex = (int)Session["index"];
        int PictureCount = (int)Session["CountOfPictures"];
        NextIndex -= 1;

        if (NextIndex == -1)
        {
            NextIndex = PictureCount - 1;
        }

        Session["index"] = NextIndex;
        var list = (List<string>)Session["AllPhotoFiles"];
        Image1.ImageUrl = list[NextIndex].Replace("\\", "//");
        lblName.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(list[NextIndex]).Substring(0, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(list[NextIndex]).Length - 4).Replace("_", " ");
        lblName.Visible = true;
    }

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <br /><br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="400px" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >    <td>
       <div style="text-align:center"> <asp:Button style="text-align:center" ID="btnPrevious" runat="server" Text="Previous" 
        onclick="btnPrevious_Click" Width="125px" />
     <asp:Button style="text-align:center" ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" onclick="btnNext_Click" 
            Width="125px" /></div></td></tr>


    </table>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Do the images appear in IE8 as broken?

Comment: What happens when you show the full url of the picture in the address bar of Firefox?

Comment: Dave, in ie8 you can see the square image outline where the picture should display and a small grey box with a rex 'X' in the upper left corner

Comment: Pieter, when i paste the photo url in firefox it displays the photo (also does the same in ie8)

Comment: This looks related to your error. http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2008/02/20/pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-status-code-500.aspx

Comment: One thing I would try is fixing `Replace("\\", "//")` to `Replace("\\", "/")` though I can't reproduce the problem in IE even with the redundant slash. Are there any unusual characters in your file names? Can you give an example of a full url (minus the domain) that doesn't work in IE?

Comment: If I only had 50 points for every time an app worked in FF but not IE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have reproduced the problem.

You are not adding http: to the url, and you are doubling the slashes. The code would appear to generate output like this:

```
<img src="////intranet.org//image//path//some_image.jpg">
```

This actually seems to work in Firefox and Chrome but not IE. The problem isn't the double-slashes between the folder/file names, it's the four of them up front.

Removing the double-slashes (as replaces each backslash from your file path) as I suggested in a comment before ought to solve it. Also consider adding "http:" to the url so it is properly formed.

Comment: I got this error "URI formats are not supported."  when i tried changing the path to "PhotoFolders.Add("http:\\intranet...."

Comment: when you view source for the HTML output what exactly is your code producing for an img?

Comment: You were right about the path.  I changed this line  Replace("\\", "//") to  Replace("\\", "/") and now it works in ie and firefox.  Thank you

Comment: @Joshua since jamietre's answer solved your problem you should award your bounty to his question. If you have questions about doing so see See "How Do I Award a Bounty": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067